# Can't Repair SR in XenCenter

Tags: storage-area-network, xenserver, fibre-channel

I've added in a 4th host to my Xen 6.2 cluster and I'm unable to get it to successfully attach to my existing storage repositories.  I'm using 3 older IBM hosts and the 4th new one which is CPU masked so that it successfully joins the pool.  I have two fibre switches, Cisco, which have the paths setup correctly for all four hosts to see the IBM san.

Currently I have 3 LUNs available in Xen Centre which are showing as connected to all hosts with the exception of the newest server which is shown as 'unplugged'.  When I try and perform a 'repair' via the GUI it fails after PBD plug with the error 'Invalid Argument'

Anyone got any ideas of where I can start to get this problem resolved.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Some further information, if I run #multipath -ll I'm told that the kernel module isn't loaded.  I've tried forcing it but it looks like a problem with multipathing

Comment: Can post kern.log and SMlog if needed

Comment: Please post `lsscsi` for the new and for one of the older hosts.

Comment: -bash: lsscsi: command not found

Answer (score 1):

XenCenter is skimpy on the error messages. Try via CLI and see if you can make more sense of the error message. http://www.schirmacher.de/display/INFO/How+to+reattach+a+disk+to+XenServer

Comment: Sorry, this didn't help.  The problem is related to multipath and I'm unable to plug a new SR without this working.